# How best to test for an empty (null) component in Vitest?

Tags: reactjs, null, react-testing-library, vitest

I have a React component which, when given badly configured props, returns `null`

`screen.debug()` in Vitest displays the result like this:

```
  <body>
    <div />
  </body>
```

This is expected, but what constitutes a good test for this markup?

Currently I'm testing the absence of tags that would be present if the component returned a JSX element. Does that sound right?

---

Comment: you can use the `shallowMount` method to mount the component and then use the `exists` method to check if the component exists.  `import { shallowMount } from '@vue/test-utils';`